# Joint density function where X=Y?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function

Today I tried solving the following question as a preparation for my Intro. to Probability 1 exam.

> Suppose X, Y have joint density f(x, y). what is the probability that X = Y ?

My first attempt was:
let $Z = X - Y$, then $P(X=Y)=P(Z=0)=0$ because Z is a continuous random variable.

But I then thought about a a counter example, where $X\sim exp(1)$ and $Y=X$ then $P(X=Y)=1$

How would I go about finding the probability here, if I have no details regarding X,Y ?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: As we do not know anything about the dependence of $X$ and $Y$ there is no way to compute the probability.  Nothing in the problem statement precludes $X=Y$, for example.

Comment: What makes you state $P(X=Y)=1$? You can at most say that $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution. If indeed $P(X=Y)=1$ (for instance if $X=Y$) then it is for certain that $X$ and $Y$ do not have a joint PDF.

Comment: Maybe we should divide the problem into cases, where X,Y are dependent and independent
@drhab Fixed that, I meant that Y=X

Comment: What I said in my former comment is dubious (sorry) so I deleted that comment. I have edited my answer. The second part is purely focused on integration and PDF's. The case $X=Y$ is not a counterexample because there is no PDF for the distribution of $(X,Y)=(X,X)$.

Comment: as mentioned by the comments and answers, $X = Y$ will makes the random vector degenerate and become a univariate distribution only. So the joint does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Delta:=\{(x,x)|x\in\Bbb R\}$ and let $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R^2$.

Then $\lambda(\Delta)=0$ and consequently:$$P(X=Y)=\int\int f(x,y)1_{\Delta}(x,y)dxdy=0$$

---

In general for Borel-measurable $$A\subseteq\mathbb R^2$$ we have:$$P((X,Y)\in A)=\int\int 1_A(x,y)f(x,y)dxdy$$Applying this on $A=\Delta$ we find:$$P(X=Y)=\int\int1_{\Delta}(x,y)f(x,y)dxdy=$$$$\int\int1_{\{y\}}(x)f(x,y)dxdy=\int0dy=0$$

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Sadly we did not go into measure theory during our course. Do you know any explanation around it? And how does this work with the counter example I've shown?

Comment: I think I understand now for the general case, but can you elaborate on the part where this also applies if X=Y? to my understanding, in this case $P(X=y|Y=y)=1$.
Thanks again for the quick answer!

Comment: What I said in my former comment is dubious (sorry) so I deleted that comment. I have edited my answer. The second part is purely focused on integration and PDF's. The case $X=Y$ is not a counterexample because there is no PDF for the distribution of $(X,Y)=(X,X)$.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. If that's ok with you, I would like to ask a clarification regrading your statement about the PDF for $(X,Y)=(X,X)$. Why is it not a counter example?
EDIT: The comment made by @BGM helped me understands, all good now!

Answer (score 0):

If $ X \sim exp(1), Y \sim exp(1) $, then $ P(X=Y) \neq $ 1.

Comment: correct, I fixed my example to a case where Y=X